# JestJS testing synchronous code shows asynchronous behavior

Tags: jestjs

I am new to JestJS and trying to test synchronous code. The following test passes alright:

```
bin = new Compiler().compile('{int a = 42;}');

test('Integer constant declaration', function() {
  expect(bin.dumpVariables()).toBe("[int const a = 42]\n");
});
```

However when I append this code:

```
bin = new Compiler().compile('{bool b;}');

test('Another test', function() { ... }
```

... the first test fails because `bin` already has the new value from the assignment that comes after it. Why is that? My code is fully synchronous so I would have expected the first test to pass and THEN the effects of the code that follows it.

Answer (score 0):

Cause `bin` lives in the scope of both test. But the main problem is that all code that is written outside of one of the `test`, `describe`, `it` blocks and so on is called immediately. Lets have a look how a `test` call looks like:

```
test('testname', testFunction)
```

this means the test is added to test suite with a name and a function, but this doesn't mean that the `testFunction` is called immediately. If it would work like this a `beforeEach` block wouldn't work. So first the test suite collects all the different `test`, `describe`, `it` calls and then it runs them. If you now create a variable in the upper scope outside of the tests it will have the value that was assigned to last. In your case `{bool b;}`